# JSTree Remove Left Space Gap Before Checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jstree

I set icons to false and have been checking the CSS for a quick fix on this issue but no luck. I created an example and you can see it has a huge amount of space on the left of each checkbox. It would seem if I remove the class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" from the li object in the output source it does go away. Is there a way to do this in the theme options?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#YearContainer").jstree({
    "plugins": ["wholerow", "checkbox"],
    core: {
      "themes": {
        "icons": false,
        "dots": false,
        "responsive": false,
        "stripes": true
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" />
<div id="YearContainer">
  <ul>
    <li>
      2010
      <ul>
        <li>
          2010A
        </li>
        <li>
          2010B
        </li>
      </ul </li>
      <li>
        2011
      </li>
      <li>
        2012
      </li>
      <li>
        2013
      </li>
      <li>
        2014
      </li>
      <li>
        2015
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: So you *don't* want to use a CSS fix?

Comment: CSS fix would be fine, when I tried that it removed the check box as well. Do you have a CSS solution that I could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy fix would just be to set the extra icon space to `display:none` like so:

```
.jstree-node.jstree-leaf > .jstree-icon.jstree-ocl {
    display: none;
}
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("#YearContainer").jstree({
    "plugins": ["wholerow", "checkbox"],
    core: {
      "themes": {
        "icons": false,
        "dots": false,
        "responsive": true,
        "stripes": true
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.jstree-node.jstree-leaf[aria-level="1"] > .jstree-icon.jstree-ocl {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" />
<div id="YearContainer">
  <ul>
    <li>
      2010
      <ul>
        <li>
          2010A
        </li>
        <li>
          2010B
        </li>
      </ul </li>
      <li>
        2011
      </li>
      <li>
        2012
      </li>
      <li>
        2013
      </li>
      <li>
        2014
      </li>
      <li>
        2015
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you very much. Any way you can clue me into how you figured that out with the greater than sign and everything? I used Firefox and was playing with the CSS for hours but it kept removing the checkboxes. The code you provided targets the first leaf then the jstree-ocl vs. what I was doing, globally changing the whole jstree-ocl class right?

Comment: @ChrisGo Yes, that's basically right. What my CSS does is finds all the items that have both the `jstree-node` and `jstree-leaf` classes (which in this case is the tree rows) and then by using the `>` operator, targets only direct descendants of that that have the classes `jstree-icon` and `jstree-ocl`. With CSS, there is always a different way of doing things - for example I could've used the selector `i.jstree-icon.jstree-ocl` but I like the one in the answer better because it's pretty clear what it targets.

Comment: I updated my code snippet for an example of a nested list. There is one small issue when using a list within a list. You do lose bullet-type indentation on the inner list as well. Maybe there is a way to only target the first instance of the class? Not a huge deal but the indentation on inner list is a bit easier for people to view.

Comment: CC Inc, Any ideas on the previous comment?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is? [This](http://imgur.com/a/jesY2) is what I see, I'm not sure what it's supposed to look like.

Comment: Put a sub list in your example with the CSS tweak and you will see the problem. Either way thanks for all the help.

Comment: Works great! I would update your text based anaser as well since that is what people are going to see first. The [aria-level="1"] did the trick nicely. Now it looks perfect. Not sure why JSTree forces that left padding but it was sure nice to get rid of it. Thank you.